# Paste multiple files in Linux command line without the blank columns between every file

Tags: linux

Whenever I try to paste multiple files with whatever columns they have, I have problem with the blank columns created between files.

For example, I want to paste five files, and each one contains five columns:

```
paste file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

Comment: What do you mean by blank columns? How are the columns separated?

Comment: if each file has 5 columns, then:   paste file1 file2 | cut -f6  gives a blank column, not the first column of the second file , ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default delimiter for paste is a tab character. You could change that by supplying the *-d* option:

```
paste -d' ' file1 file2 ...
```

---

Based on information in comments above, it seems that the input files have spaces/tab at the end of lines. Try saying:

```
paste <(sed 's/\s$//' file1) <(sed 's/\s$//' file2) ...
```

Comment: Thats a nice command!
I have more than 3000 files which I want to merge side-by-side. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that file1, file2, file3, and file4 have superfluous whitespace at the end of each line.

I'd recommend not generating those superfluous tabs in the first place, but if you have no control over how they are generated, you can get rid of them with `sed` or `tr`.

Also, you state that `paste file1 file2 | cut -f6` gives a blank column, but if you use `awk` instead of `cut` (see the info page for GNU cut) you won't have this problem anyway.